# Using spring-loaded with tomcat webapps

Tags: tomcat, web-applications, classloader, alfresco, spring-loaded

(SOLVED) I have been trying out Spring-loaded as an open-source variant of Rebel or others for hot-deploy/class reloading of Java code. However I have not had succes with the JVM agent configuration using springloaded-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar as described here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-loaded.

- Is it possible to get tomcat webapp class reloading working with spring-loaded and what should the configuration be?

Comment: What exactly is your problem ? Where (in the classpath) do you expect the jvm to pick up class changes ?

Comment: from the deployed webapps, EX. tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF and classes or lib (jars)

Comment: Classes from jars are not supported. You sure files in WEB-INF/classes actually change and the JVM does not pick up the changes ?

Comment: I have tested with class files deployed instead of JAR, deploying new classes checking they have new timestamps and change some code. But i do not see logging statements from spring-loaded either even after setting org.springsource to FINEST

Comment: The question seems solved. Can you share what solved your problem?

Comment: Yes, the unpacked JAR (instead of packed), so that spring-loaded can see the class files directly ... I up'ed the comment from Andreas S.